# Typescript - Multiple setInterval calls

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function in which I'd like several `setInterval` calls, however the code within in them is very similar.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could better write this to avoid code duplication:

```
(async (): Promise<void> => {

    // 1 min interval check
    const oneMin = setInterval(async function () {
        Detail.find({ interval: 1 }, async function (err, toCheck) {
            // The Same Logic
        })
    }, minutesToMS(1));

    // 10 min interval check
    const tenMin = setInterval(async function () {
        Detail.find({ interval: 10 }, async function (err, toCheck) {
            // The Same Logic
        })
    }, minutesToMS(10));

})();
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this part:

```
async function (err, toCheck) {
  // The Same Logic
}
```

into a standalone variable first, so you can pass it to both `.find`s:

```
type CallbackType = Parameters<typeof Detail.find>[1];
const callback: CallbackType = async (err, toCheck) => {
    // logic
};
// 1 min interval check
setInterval(function () {
    Detail.find({ interval: 1 }, callback)
}, minutesToMS(1));

// 10 min interval check
setInterval(function () {
    Detail.find({ interval: 10 }, callback)
}, minutesToMS(10));
```

If you also want to avoid repeating the `{ interval: 1 }` `minutesToMS(1)`, then:

```
type CallbackType = Parameters<typeof Detail.find>[1];
const callback: CallbackType = async (err, toCheck) => {
    // logic
};
const makeInterval = (interval) => {
    setInterval(function () {
        Detail.find({ interval }, callback)
    }, minutesToMS(interval));
};
makeInterval(1);
makeInterval(10);
```

Comment: Cool - that looks good.
By the way having those multiple setIntervals in one function, I had to declare each setInterval into its own variable like `const oneMin`, `const tenMin` etc. It works, but of course my linter complains about the unused variable. Any ideas on that?

Comment: If you only need to initialize the interval, but not use the returned interval ID, then just don't assign the result to a variable

Comment: Also in the line `type CallbackType = Parameters<typeof Detail.find>[1]` what does that `[1]` refer to? DIdnt quite understand it

Comment: But then can I use multiple `setIntervals` in one function?

Comment: This is good, but you could go a step further and create: `function createSetInterval(interval: number) { return setInterval(....); }`

Comment: The question is tagged with Typescript, so I assume this is TS - if you want the `callback` function (its parameters and return type) to be typed correctly, TS needs to know its shape. This can be done by either listing all the possible types manually, or (a better option) by using `Parameters` to extract the type of the `Details.find` function, and `[1]` to extract the second parameter

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance - got it. so [0] would just refer to the `{ interval: 10 }`?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the type of that object, looks like `{ interval: number }` or something similar